# MapReduce Linear Programming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing, linear-programming

Can a simple linear programming problem be solved on a distributed system using MapReduce?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can check [hbase-simplex](https://github.com/xebia/hbase-simplex)